# The kernel keeps crashing when I attempt to use the CBC solver from the mip package

Tags: python, kernel, coin-or-cbc

```
import mip
m = mip.Model(solver_name=mip.CBC)
```

I've tried everything, but it doesn't seem to matter; the kernel still keeps dying after running this code. Reinstalling the package didn't help, although it shows that this package is installed in my Python environment. any ideas?

I attempted to use the CBC solver from the mip package in Python. My expectation was that the solver would function properly, allowing me to optimize a linear programming model without any issues. However, contrary to my expectations, each time I executed the code, the Python kernel crashed unexpectedly. Despite trying various solutions, such as reinstalling the mip package and ensuring it was correctly installed in my Python environment, the problem persisted. The kernel's consistent crashing upon running the code remains unresolved

Comment: Are you getting errors? Anything in any logs? Is the CBC solver binary is correctly installed and accessible to the `mip` package? Did you reinstall Python itself?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors when running the provided code in my environment. Since I am not encountering any errors, there are no relevant logs to report from my end. 
import mip

model = mip.Model()
print("Solver name:", model.solver_name)
to check if it is accessible, but after running this code it gets crashed(after the line 2). yes I've tried to reinstall python but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Solution: After installing a Python version lower than 3.12, the issue with the kernel crashing has been resolved.